# Clarification on differentiability definitions

Tags: limits, derivatives

How do I prove that $h_x(0,1)$ and $h_y(0,1)$ exist?

Suppose I were to prove that $h_x(0,1)$ and $h_y(0,1)$ exist, given $h(x,y)$

Do I use

$h_x(0,1)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x,1)-h(0,1)}{x-0}$ and
$h_y(0,1)=\lim_{y\to 1} \frac{h(0,y)-h(0,1)}{y-0}$

or is the numerator/denominator incorrect?

Comment: What does $h_x(0,1)$ mean? Do you mean the partial derivative of a function of two variables at the point $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly noted, this is a matter of definition. Such questions are actually open ended, because we can chose the definition to be whatever we want. This said, you want
$$
    h_x(0,1)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x,1)-h(0,1)}{x-0}
$$
and
$$
    h_y(0,1)=\lim_{y\to 1} \frac{h(0,y)-h(0,1)}{y-1}.
$$
So, the second denominator was incorrect, easy to fix!

The general pattern is
$$
    h_x(a,b)=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{h(x,b)-h(a,b)}{x-a}
$$
and
$$
    h_y(a,b)=\lim_{y\to b} \frac{h(a,y)-h(a,b)}{y-b}.
$$